Looking for a 70's/80's book about a Colony Ship That Crashes
This is a book I borrowed from the library when I was in Junior/Senior high. The plot is that the colony ship crashes and the colonists try to survive. They all were given jobs to carry out, but they don't know what those jobs are, and they need to figure it out.
One guy, the male protagonist, find out he is a road builder who is meant to be away from home building roads all the time. His wife and he argue a lot, but they discover that it's because they're not supposed to spend a lot of time together.
Oh, the cover has them in sorta modern clothes (but torn and ragged) with the guy building a road and looking super buff with his shirt open.
Any ideas?
Thanks!
